# Change value based on conditions when iterrating

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to iterate over rows in my data frame and change every value in the column `Currency Leverage` if it satisfies two conditions: a) row in column `Balance` is equal to zero b) row in column `Currency Leverage` is also equal to zero. That value supposed to be replaced by the previous value.

```
for index, row in df['AUDUSD'].iterrows():
   if row['Balance'] == 0 and row['Currency Leverage'] == 0:
      row['Currency Leverage'] = row['Currency Leverage'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')

   else:
      continue
```

I am getting an Attribute error: numpy.float64 object has no atrribute replace

The dataframe:

```
                    Balance  $ Currency Volume  Currency Leverage
Time                                                                     
2019-01-01 00:00:00  4000000.000000           0.000000           0.000000
2019-01-03 00:34:59        0.000000           0.000000           0.000000
2019-01-03 00:39:27        0.000000           0.000000           0.000000
2019-01-03 00:43:07  4000000.000000      -67945.800000          -0.016986
2019-01-03 00:43:07  4000000.000000      -90594.400000          -0.022649
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I think something similar to the following code should work:

```
bool_index = (df['Balance'] == 0) & (df['Currency Leverage'] == 0)
val_index = np.array(df.index[bool_index].tolist()) - 1
df.loc[bool_index, 'Currency Leverage'] = df.iloc[val_index, 'Currency Leverage']
```

Comment: You should avoid iterating on rows, when you work with dataframes. Use indexing

Comment: Thank you xkudsraw. The first solution is not working as I didn't set frequency for the DatetimeIndex. The frequency is not consistent  and is precise on a second. If I change the freq to one second I will have even bigger dataset.
To the second solution, can you advise me what would be a different solution then?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Where does DatetimeIndex appear in your original question? Or the reference to the frequencies?

Comment: When I use the above mention solution, I get an Value error: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq (refering to the line 2).

Comment: Try to share a part of the dataframe, to test the solution

Comment: I added a sample of the dataframe above to my query

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the times that you use as index. Try to store them somewhere and reset the indices. Then, perform the computation as I suggested. Then, put the time indices back

Comment: This works! However, I get a new error now. ValueError: location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slide (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types. It is refering to the "= df.iloc[val_index, 'Currency Leverage']".

Comment: Try using df.iloc[val_index.astype(int), 'Currency Leverage']

Comment: I fix this error, in the end, by changing it to: "df['Currency Leverage'].iloc[val_index]. Although it still doen't make the job. I assume "val_index" is supposed to choose the indexes for the rows fullfiling the conditions? It returns an array with all the indexes.

Comment: you can pass to iloc the row indices that you want to select (to .loc you have to pass the dataframe index values (being those a number, a string, a time, as in your case, etc) or a boolean with conditions for all rows).

Comment: val_index should select the "previous values". As you stated: "That value supposed to be replaced by the previous value."

Comment: It's just that there isn't any change in the column Currency Leverage, the values remain the same as before. Although I think I understand your solution and I see why it is better one.

Comment: Have you actually checked that the previous values are actually different that the ones that they have to replace? In the sample of the dataframe that you shared, there was no change, for example.

Comment: I did, I can see a row where there are everywhere zeros and the previous row is filled with numbers.

Comment: Can you actually check that the indices in bool_index and val_index are different? You will need to (df.index[bool_index] and val_index should be shifted by one, as it is supposed, by the definition)

Comment: In the end, I fix the issue by setting all the values meeting both conditions to NaN values (by defining bool_index and val_index without shifting the indexes as stated above). Then I used the ffillna(method='ffill"). The values which were zero in the levereage column but did not satisfied the other condition remained zero.